# How to fetch shopify products based on multiple varying tags which are given dynamically in python?

Tags: graphql, shopify, shopify-api, shopify-api-node

I am trying to fetch products from shopify by filtering based on tags. Tags will be dynamic, more than one, and will change.

```
import json
import time
import requests

API_KEY = 'xxxx'
PASSWORD = 'xxxx'
SHOP_NAME = 'xxxx'
API_VERSION = '2020-04' #change to the API version
shop_url = "https://%s:%s@%s.myshopify.com/admin/api/%s" % (API_KEY, PASSWORD, SHOP_NAME, API_VERSION)

def callShopifyGraphQL(GraphQLString, data):
    headers = {
        "X-Shopify-Storefront-Access-Token": 'xxxxxx',
        "accept":"application/json"      
    }
    response = requests.post(shop_url+'/graphql', json={'query': GraphQLString, 'variables': data}, headers=headers)
    answer = json.loads(response.text)
    return answer['data']

str1 = '0-12'
str2 = 'physical'

graphQLquery7 = """ {
  products(first:100, query:"tag:$tags") {
    edges {
      node {
        id
        tags
        title
        onlineStoreUrl
      }
    }
  }
}"""

tag = dict({
  "tags":[str1,str2]
})

resp = callShopifyGraphQL(graphQLquery7, tag)
print json.dumps(resp)


# This query works fine and gives multiple products
# graphQLquery2 = """{
#   products(first:100, query:"tag:[0-12, physical]") {
#     edges {
#       cursor
#       node {
#         id
#         tags
        
#         title
#         onlineStoreUrl
#       }
#     }
#   }
# }"""
```

The Output that I am getting is basically a JSON with products empty

```
{u'extensions': {u'cost': {u'requestedQueryCost': 102, u'throttleStatus': {u'restoreRate': 50.0, u'currentlyAvailable': 998, u'maximumAvailable': 1000.0}, u'actualQueryCost': 2}}, u'data': {u'products': {u'edges': []}}}
{"products": {"edges": []}}
```

I am unable to pass my tags as a variable in the query.  I am currently using GraphQl because I couldn't find REST APIs fetch product based on multiple tags which would vary.

EDIT: Removed Python tag as this was not a python issue and I have added the answer as well lisitng two methods on how to do this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally found the answer to my own question ->

1. The first way is a workaround(or a cheap python trick) which might be applicable only for the scenario mentioned in the question. Since the query is being passed in as a string(a multiline string), I can simply use placeholders to add variables in it by abusing the line continuation properties of the parenthesis `(` and the comma `,`.

```
graphQLquery1 = """ {
  products(first:100, query:"tag:[%s, %s]") {
    edges {
      node {
        id
        tags
        title
        onlineStoreUrl
      }
    }
  }
}"""%('3+', 'personal-social')

data = None
resp = callShopifyGraphQL(graphQLquery1, data)
```

However, this is not how one should use variables in a GraphQl query.

2. Below is a more proper solution of using variables in GraphQl

```
graphQLquery2 = """ query($tags: String){
products(first:100, query:$tags) {
    edges {
      node {
        id
        tags
        title
        onlineStoreUrl
      }
    }
  }
}"""

str1 = '0-12'
str2 = 'physical'
tags = dict({
  "tags":[str1,str2]
})
resp = callShopifyGraphQL(graphQLquery2, tags)
```

Answer (score 5):

You must use the flowing syntax:

```
{
  products(first:10, query:"tag:tag1 OR tag:tag2 OR tag:tag3"){
    edges {
      node {
        id
        tags
        title
        onlineStoreUrl
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Where you can use `OR` or `AND` if you like for all of the tags to be included or any of the listed.

Install the [GraphiQL App](https://www.electronjs.org/apps/graphiql) and test the queries before implementing them, it helps a lot in the development process.

More about the Search Query for GraphQL can be seen here: https://shopify.dev/concepts/about-apis/search-syntax

Comment: I know how to search products based on multiple tags. How will I pass those dynamically as a variable/argument? I am writing an API that fetches product with given set of tags. Tags can change and are dynamic.  Look at the commented part of code as well

Comment: @HARSHITBAJPAI I'm not a Python expert (I haven't touch it for years) by I assume that it has string concatenation. I don't see what is the problem to convert your array/dictionary in a string and pass it. If there is some limitation that I don't know about Python string manipulation please ignore my answer. :)

Comment: I just removed the python tag as this was not a python issue. I just posted an answer to this question illustrating two methods for this. You can mark that as correct if you find it useful and appropriate @drip –

Answer (score 1):

Since that was also asked in the comments (this [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62779854/how-to-fetch-shopify-products-based-on-multiple-varying-tags-which-are-given-dyn#comment111023263_62781635) by Harshit Bajpai), thought I'd answer.

To make this a query call with a passable param:

```
const GetProductsByTag = gql`
  query GetProductsByTag($first: Int!, $query: String!) {
    products(first: $first, query: $query) {
      edges {
        node {
          id
          title
          handle
          tags
        }
      }
    }
  }
`
```